# how to hide ssrs rdl parameter programatically from code?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using ssrs rdl reports in my asp.net web application. I want to hide/show a rdl parameter from C# code based on condition.

for example, if user is admin, he can see customer selection filter, or else if he login as a normal user, he can not see that filter

Answer (score 0):

[ReportParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportparameter_members%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has `Visible` property. Set it to `false` to hide it from user interface.